# Creating USB boot disc for ubuntu

Tags: boot, macosx, unetbootin

I am using Mac OS X 10.9 and am trying to create a boot usb of `ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso`. I have tried Unetbootin, but the installation halts at step 2 file 254. I have verified the md5 is correct.

I also tried:

```
sudo dd if=/Volumes/BETHY/ubuntu-14.10-desktop-amd64.iso of= /dev/disk1s1 bs=1m
```

I have used multiple thumb drives. any idea?

EDIT : managed to create a usb boot disc (i think), it does not work. is there any way to verify the usb created ?

Comment: The `filesystem.squashfs` file is much bigger compared to the rest and hence takes a long time to copy. If that is the file you are stuck on, wait for some time.

Comment: It shouldn't take so long. Something else is the problem.

Comment: Is the USB formatted as FAT/FAT32?

Comment: @RohithMadhavan interprets your question like `dd` is taking too long, but does it actually? Can you invoke `dd` again and then `echo $?` right after?

Comment: I had formatted the drives to FAT32, but after trying a very old flash disk (the 3rd one). However, when I try run it on the windows pc I am wanting to install it on it does not work. I select the usb drive, and it just does not boot. It stalls on a black screen with a flashing white underscore. Thanks your all your great responses thus far Roh

Answer (score 0):

I used `unetbootin` to create an Ubuntu 14.04 installation on a USB stick but had to go through some hoops to make it work. First is that the USB drive *must* be formatted as a `vfat` filesystem. That filesystem should be on the first partition, better if it's the only partition. Then mount the USB stick somewhere (change the device so that it is the drive letter of your USB stick (mine was `/dev/sdb1`), and change the mount point to one that works for your system):

```
$ mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
```

I do not use OS X, so you will need to sort out how to access the command line and gain root privileges. Next call `unetbootin` from the command line giving it the following arguments:

```
$ unetbootin installtype=USB targetdrive=/dev/sdb1  (or your target drive letter).
```

That should start the `unetbootin` GUI and allow you to chose your installation file and write it to the USB stick.

Comment: Man, this is way over my head. Sorry. I am going to try research what you said and try implement it. Thanks for your response